# (Matrix Calculus) Chain Rule

Tags: matrix-calculus

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be an invertible matrix, $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\kappa: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ . What is $\frac{\partial\ \kappa(A^{-1}v)}{\partial\ A}$?

I've been trying all sorts of equations from the Matrix Cookbook, but none of them leads to success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For convenience, let's define two new vector variables
$$\eqalign{
 x &= A^{-1}v \cr
 g &= \frac{\partial\kappa}{\partial x} \cr
}$$
Also, let's use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e. 
$$A:BC = {\rm tr}(A^TBC)$$
The properties of the trace give rise to lots of rules for rearranging the terms in a Frobenius product, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
 A:BC &= BC:A \cr &= AC^T:B \cr &= B^TA:C \cr
}$$
Write the differential and gradient of the function in terms of these new variables
$$\eqalign{
d\kappa
 &= g:dx \cr
 &= g:dA^{-1}\,v \cr
 &= -gv^T:A^{-1}\,dA\,A^{-1} \cr
 &= -A^{-T}gv^TA^{-T}:dA \cr
\frac{\partial\kappa}{\partial A} &= -A^{-T}gv^TA^{-T} \cr
}$$
From your other comments, we have an expression for $g$ which we can substitute
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial\kappa}{\partial A}
 &= -A^{-T}(-\kappa x)v^TA^{-T} \cr
 &= \kappa A^{-T}A^{-1}vv^TA^{-T} \cr
}$$

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much! I find all those different layout conventions so confusing and I'm never sure whether the chain rule is valid for higher-order tensors...but you made it look so easy! Didn't know the trace was so useful! Thanks again!!

Comment: It occurs to me that you can make this result look a bit cleaner by writing it as $$\kappa A^{-T}xx^T$$

Comment: I went through your derivation: The only thing that's not clear to me is why we can write $\textrm{d}\kappa$ as $\textrm{tr}(g^\top\textrm{d}x)$.

Comment: One of the defining characteristic of a gradient is that (fully) contracting it with the differential of the independent variable yields the differential of the dependent variable. Here's an example using index notation and high-order tensors for generality: $$dF_{ijk} = \Bigg(\frac{\partial F_{ijk}}{\partial X_{npqr}}\Bigg)\,dX_{npqr}$$ The thing in parentheses being the gradient. Of course, things are much simpler when working with mere vectors and matrices.

Comment: In the present case, $$d\kappa = g_k dx_k=\Big(\frac{\partial\kappa}{\partial x_k}\Big) dx_k$$ which can also be written as a trace or scalar product, instead of index notation.

Comment: Wish I could upvote your answer multiple times. I really want to learn how to use this technique in my daily work; it's so elegant. For instance: Now that we now the answer for $\frac{\partial \kappa}{\partial A}$, can we reuse this knowledge to infer $\frac{\partial \kappa}{\partial AA^\top}$? Naively, $\frac{\partial \kappa}{\partial A}=\frac{\partial \kappa}{\partial AA^\top}\cdot \frac{\partial AA^\top}{\partial A}$, but that obviously doesn't make any sense, because the second factor is a 4th order tensor; this is exactly the issue I keep running into when trying to use the chain rule.

Answer (score 2):

You can decompose your function as

$$
 f = \kappa \circ h \circ g
$$

where

$$
 g(X) =X^{-1} \quad ; \quad h(X) = Xv .
$$
In differential form

$$
 d \kappa = \langle \nabla \kappa(\mathbb{x}), d\mathbb{x} \rangle  
\quad ; \quad
 d h =  (dX) v \quad ; \quad 
 d g = - X^{-1} (dX) X^{-1} .
$$
Then, by applying chain rule we get differental of $f$

$$
 d f = -\Big\langle \nabla \kappa(A^{-1}v), A^{-1} (dA) A^{-1} v  \Big\rangle.
$$

You can compute derivative in form of matrix

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial A} (A) = (x_{i,j} )^n_{i,j = 1},
$$

where each entry has a value

$$
x_{i,j} = -\Big\langle \nabla \kappa(A^{-1}v), A^{-1}  X_{i,j} A^{-1} v \Big \rangle
$$

with $X_{i,j}$ being a matrix with $1$ at position $i,j$ and $0$ everywhere else.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! With respect to what is the gradient taken? I was hoping for an expression in terms of matrices, because this is only one term of a larger equation. Does it help that I know $\frac{\partial \kappa(u)}{\partial u}= -\kappa(u)\cdot u$?